# How can I navigate from Bootstrap 5 validation eventlistener

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do this in plain javascript. I lifted the following code directly from the [Bootstrap 5 validation sample](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/forms/validation/#custom-styles):

```js
  // Loop over them and prevent submission
  Array.from(forms).forEach((form) => {
    form.addEventListener(
      'submit',
      (event) => {
        if (!form.checkValidity()) {
          event.preventDefault()
          event.stopPropagation()
          console.log("!form.checkValidity()")
        } else {
          // save data, then redirect
          console.log("form.checkValidity()")
          // window.location.href="" and replace() don't work
        }

        form.classList.add('was-validated')

      },
      false
    )
  })
```

Everything works swimmingly and the `form.checkValidity() == true` case fires as expected. But I can't figure out how to navigate to a new page once I have verified the data and saved it. Am I missing something simple? How do I navigate to a page on the same site (e.g. "page2.html") in this eventlistener?

Comment: Shouldn’t successful validation result in a form submit? That would be `event.target.submit();`.

Comment: Should I instead be setting up the button and adding an eventlistener for the "click" event, not the "submit" event?

Comment: No. Why would you do that?

Comment: There are 2 more pages to go through before I am ready to "submit" anything.

Comment: @SebastianSimon your initial comment gave me the hint I needed - I need to `event.preventDefault` in the "successful validation" clause, then I can save the data locally and navigate.

Comment: Exactly, the problem is that the default submit action (redirecting the page to the `action` of the form with the provided form data) takes precedence over your custom `location` setting. So you really should consider using the `action` attribute. It also appears that if you use the `required` attributes and possibly others, e.g. `pattern`, then the `submit` event won’t even be triggered to begin with. I don’t think you even need this JS code at all.

Comment: I will look into the `action` attribute - thanks, I've been out of the raw js world for several years. Just getting my feet wet again!